Why Volumetric efficiency is not considered as a performance parameter in case of 2 stroke engines

This mentioned in almost all standard books that for two stroke we use scavenging efficiency and trapping efficiency, but does not mention the reason, why volumetric efficiency is not used.

You are misinterpreting what the volumetric efficiency is in 2-stroke engines. You need a better reference, mine is Internal Combustion Engines by Obert, Harper & Row, 1973.
Volumetric (charging) efficiency is the mass of air retained in the cylinder over the mass of air to fill the displacement volume.
The problem in a 2-stroke is that the lack of a specific intake stroke forces us to measure the air masses indirectly.  We can't use geometry. So we use delivery and scavenging ratios.
Deliv ratio = mass of air supplied over mass of air to fill the displacement volume.
Scav ratio = mass of air supplied over mass of air to fill the cylinder volume.
Which when combined results in:
Trapping efficiency [that more closely relates to what is going on in the cylinder], mass of air retained over mass of air supplied.
Volumetric (charging)  eff = delivery ratio times trapping efficiency.
So there are more variables to making an efficient 2-stroke engine than compression ratio, namely how to get the exhaust gasses out and intake gasses in.
